# Add date filter list in Tableau

Tags: filter, tableau-api, week-number

I have created time series dashboard where x-axis are week numbers (May4, 2020, etc.). The week number I have created from actual week number and year:

```
DATETRUNC('week',DATEPARSE("w-yyyy",STR([Week])+"-"+ STR([Year])))
```

Now I want to create a list filter, so I can only select one weeks from X week selected. Anyway, when I do it, it shows as "week 23", "week 24", etc.

Is there a way of actually showing as list of filters "May4, 2020", "May11, 2020", etc. instead?

This is how it shows now:
[image]
[image]

Comment: You may use Alias for filter values

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. This is not Idea. Every week there will be a new week number therefore I would have to updated it manually every week.

Comment: Ok.  Got it.  Can you post some sample excel file to work around?

Comment: How can I attach here an excel file? I cannot find the way of doing it...

Comment: Upload it on drive and then paste a link here

Comment: let me know if this works .   https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1qxDQUdwcHo0HUc-4D2ulpV4ZowkslD-b-Ypg1RdI5jY/edit#gid=0

Answer (score -1):

Doesn't using your calculated field

```
DATETRUNC('week',DATEPARSE("w-yyyy",STR([Week])+"-"+ STR([Year])))
```

as the filter field do this?

Comment: what so you meam?

Comment: I mean put that field as a filter instead of the week number field

Comment: Now I get. Yes I do use DATETRUNC(...) for the filter.

That is what I did and it is how it shows on the pic I have attached. IT shows as "week XX"

Comment: Ok. Have you tried formatting the pill on the filter shelf to show the exact date?

Answer (score -1):

stupid thing. Only needed to change to discret the calculated value and done.